# Validation Expression for UserName using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am developing a login form with User Name and Password. I want the user to create the username in a specified format. So i am using RegularExpressionValidator for the username. What is the Validation Expression for this format.

The format is:

xyz\\t4z4567  (characters are not case sensitive)

Rules:

1. The username will be created in the above format.
2. first 5 characters(xyz\) are same for every username with the slashes.
3. Only "t4z4567" will be changed for every user.

Please provide me the solution.

Comment: which parts of the expression are fixed?  does the first part have to be 3 characters?  are the T and Z required in those locations?

Comment: This is not a format, its a bunch of letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression : `"[a-zA-Z]{3}\\\\[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d{4}"`

Based on your edit, this one should be correct :

```
"xyz\\\\[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d{4}"
```

This expression is assuming the specific order of letters and digits as provided in your example. If the last 6 digits can all be letters or digits, then this expression should be sufficient :

```
"xyz\\\\\w{6}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is link to my blog article about [validate username in c#](http://blog.platformular.com/2012/03/03/how-to-validate-username-in-c-regular-expression/)

```
  string pattern;
  pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{5,11}$";

  Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
  return regex.IsMatch(username);
```

Using the code above, username has to be start with letters and contains letters and number characters in 6 to 12 length.